# How to cause a compile-time or lint-time error if code is referencing non-exist Flutter assets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some flutter assets, say, `file_one.png`, `file_two.json` etc, and I use them in my code using `Image.asset`, `Lottie` and so on.

The problem is, how to cause a compile-time or lint-time error if code is referencing non-exist Flutter assets? For example, if I write `Image.asset('assets/not_exist_file.png')`, I hope I can get an error **at compile time** instead of at runtime. Since this can be statically checked and a compile-time or lint-time error is much, much better than a bug at runtime.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You could use a builder to generate Dart file with variables which points to your resources (just some String variables with the path to each assert). This file is generated based on your current resources when running the builder so if a resource is missing, you should get a compile error for code pointing to a variable that does no longer exist (after rerunning your builder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_gen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen) package to automatically generate an `Assets` class so that later you can access your assets in a compile-time safe way.

**Example:**

Image file in `assets/images/chip.jpg`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image(image: Assets.images.chip);
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Assets.images.chip.image(
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  );

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image.asset(Assets.images.chip.path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed I already found that later :)